# {noun} vs {noun} + -tion : What can be said generally?

Tags: difference

In general, what are the similarities and differences between: a noun and a noun with the same morpheme but with the  suffix *-tion*? What does the suffix *-tion* change and import?

I exemplify pairs (of nouns; their status as verbs is irrelevant here), which still  confuse me:

'implement' vs 'implementation'
['limit' vs 'limitation'](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236323)
'protest' vs 'protestation'
(US Supreme Court Justice Blackmun used the latter [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herrera_v._Collins#Blackmun.27s_dissent))

Comment: Why do you say these are nouns? Can't they also be verbs? Implement. Limit. Protest. Perhaps this will be of interest: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=protestation%2Climitation%2Cimplementation&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprotestation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Climitation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimplementation%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TRomano Yes, they can be. But their verbal forms are noncontextual here. That's what I meant.

Comment: My point is that the -ation suffix isn't tacked onto the noun. It all begins with the verb.

Comment: What, if anything, does the ngram teach us?

Answer (score 2):

The *-[a][t]ion* (or *-sion*) suffix on verbs means *an instance where {verb}ing occurs (or did occur, or will occur)*.  "Instance" here can be a physical thing, act, or event ("indicating state, condition, action, process, or result" according to [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-tion)).

> expansion - an instance where expanding took place.
>
> implementation - an instance where implementing something took place.
>
> limitation - an instance where limiting something took place.
>
> protestation (uncommon) - an instance where protesting took place.

Answer (score 0):

We have many nouns ending in **-ation**. Some of them will have entered the language during the Middle English period via Old French,  and some will have entered it later via Latin directly. When they entered the English language, these words were not in the core vocabulary acquired by native speakers before they learned how to read, and the same is true today. These words are mainly scientific, medical, legal, and philosophical terms.

In very general terms, the **-ation** suffix might be called a "verb-nominalizer", that is, it creates a noun from the bare infinitive verb to which the suffix is attached.

Visit -> Visitation  (a being-visited)

Limit -> Limitation (a being-limited)

Implement ->  Implementation (a being-implemented)

But "a being {verbed}" is hardly a definition; that is not an attempt to say what such a  word means; it is just an attempt to say how they are formed.

That there are other nominal forms of these verbs (*visit, limit, implement* are, after all, nouns too) does not mean that both noun forms refer to the same concept or have the same set of meanings.

The OP asks:

> In general, what are the similarities and differences between: a noun
>   and a noun with the same morpheme but with the suffix -tion?

It is impossible to state the differences in meaning between *visit* and *visitation* using **f(x)** notation or any other kind of generalized formula.

Prisoners look forward to *visits* and *visitations* in a very different way, for example.

That an automobile is incapable of exceeding 110 MPH may be its *limit*, but that top speed may prove to be no *limitation* whatsoever if the car is intended for normal commuting in and around town.